# 301 Redirects in GoogleApp Engine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've got a WordPress site completed and ready for a client to upload to Google App Engine, however, I'm going to have to help them set up some 301 redirects for the new site. They are going to be doing the preparation and upload to the main site, as they have their software product hosted on Google Apps and don't want to risk anything going wrong by giving me access.

That being said, a lot of their blog posts and some pages are going to require 301 redirects. If I do the work setting those up with a plugin, such as [Redirection](https://redirection.me), will they continue to work once the site is deployed and live?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMHO you should detail how you plan to do the redirects

Comment: My question's been edited!